# Android: OptionMenu between Activity and Fragments

Tags: android, menu, android-fragments, optionmenu

In my app I have one Activity that hosts two Fragments. If I add a MenuItem to the Menu can I retrive it in my fragments? What's the link between OptionMenu in Activity and OptionMenu in his child fragments?

Comment: Whats the reason for wantin to retrieve the menuItem in the fragments ? Usually you just want to add to the menu from the fragments and thats just a matter of overriding onCreateOptionsMenu in the fragments and calling setHasOptionsMenu(true) in their onCreate method

Answer (score 5):

You have to call `setHasOptionsMenu();` with the `true` as the argument passed to it then you can override onCreate options menu.

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // Enable the option menu for the Fragment
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
}
```

If you want to have different optionsMenu for each fragment you will define two different menu xml file and inflate them in the `onCreateOptionsMenu`

```
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);

    inflater.inflate(R.menu.fragment1_menu, menu);


}
```

Comment: It shows 2 menus.. 1 from my activity and 1 in fragment. Do u know how to hide activity menu. which i have in all fragments

Comment: I think you should not inflate menu in your Activity to avoid that.

Comment: try setting menu.removeItem(R.id.parentMenuItem); in fragment to avoid repetition

Answer (score 0):

You cannot catch the event of the activity's menu in sub fragments. Instead, you can have your fragments implement something like [`MenuItem.OnMenuItemClickListener`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MenuItem.OnMenuItemClickListener.html). And in your activity's [`onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onOptionsItemSelected%28android.view.MenuItem%29) method, you simply call `YourFragment`.[`onMenuItemClick()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MenuItem.OnMenuItemClickListener.html#onMenuItemClick%28android.view.MenuItem%29).

Answer (score 0):

I found out that I can add `MenuItem` in the Activity `onCreateOptionsMenu()` and then retrieve them in the `Fragment`s by their id, like this:

Activity:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
     itemId= 0;
     menu.add(0, itemId, 0, "item");
     return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

Fragment:

```
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
    itemId= 0
    MenuItem menuItem= menu.findItem(itemId);                         
}
```